# Replace one color using SVG filters

Tags: canvas, svg, svg-filters

Is it possible to take an IMG picture and replace one exact color to another, say #fff to #000, keeping all other colors unchanged? Probably color matrix from SVG filters can help?

Answer (score 14):

This is trivial to do with Canvas. It is also possible to do with SVG, but it's convoluted. The following method works with conventional fully opaque images. First, you convert every non-matching color value in each channel to zero and every matching color value to 1 using a long ComponentTransfer (the index of the sole "1" in your 256 member tableValues arrays should match your r, g, and b replace value). Then you zero out the alpha of everything except the resulting white pixels using a color matrix. You use the result as a mask with an feFlood of your target color and composite the result on top of your original graphic. For example, the following code replaces a specific color - rgb(87, 78, 29) - with blue.

```html
<svg width="600px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <defs>
    <filter id="color-replace" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <!-- Replace rgb(87,78,29) with blue. -->
      <feComponentTransfer >
        <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
        <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
        <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>

      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0
                                           0 1 0 0 0
                                           0 0 1 0 0
                                           1 1 1 1 -3" result="selectedColor"/>

      <feFlood flood-color="blue"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="selectedColor"/>
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g filter="url(#color-replace)">
    <rect  x="50" y="50" height="100" width="100" fill="rgb(86,77,28)"/>
    <rect  x="250" y="50" height="100" width="100" fill="rgb(86,77,29)"/>
    <rect  x="450" y="50" height="100" width="100" fill="rgb(86,78,29)"/>
    <rect  x="50" y="250" height="100" width="100" fill="rgb(87,77,29)"/>
    <rect  x="250" y="250" height="100" width="100" fill="rgb(87,78,29)"/>
    <rect  x="450" y="250" height="100" width="100" fill="rgb(87,78,30)"/>
    <rect  x="50" y="450" height="100" width="100" fill="rgb(88,78,30)"/>
    <rect  x="250" y="450" height="100" width="100" fill="rgb(88,79,29)"/>
    <rect  x="450" y="450" height="100" width="100" fill="rgb(88,79,30)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

UPDATE:

If you want to replace the original color with a color that has less than 1 opacity, then you need to take an extra step - and remove the selected color before replacing it. You can extent the filter in this way to accomplish that.

```
  <--snipping first half of filter -->

  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0
                                       0 1 0 0 0
                                       0 0 1 0 0
                                       1 1 1 1 -3" result="selectedColor"/>

  <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" result="notSelectedColor"/>
  <feFlood flood-color="blue" flood-opacity="0.5"/>
  <feComposite operator="in" in2="selectedColor"/>
  <feComposite operator="over" in2="notSelectedColor"/>
</filter>
```

Comment: I just used a variant of this code to replace the background color within an iframe. Thanks!

Comment: This works really well, but what if you also want your target color to have a different alpha, like 0.5? `flood-color="blue" flood-opacity="0.5"` doesn't seem to work, neither does setting 128 "0" and 128 "1" in a `<feFuncA/>`'s tableValues.

Comment: Added an update to allow you the replacement color to be variable opacity.

Comment: This approach does not work in Chrome (testing in 77), or precisely in any webkit based browser. Only Firefox is handling it right. The problem seems to be with the `feComponentTransfer` where `tableValues` is intepreted in a rather odd way by Chrome.

Comment: This still works in my Chrome 77/Win10. There are a couple of Chrome GPU flags that hork filters - maybe you have one of those set?

Comment: I'm not able to get it working either, on Chrome 78 / OSX 10.14.5 when I try it in codepad or run the code snippet via SO