# Extract Specific Pixel Colors with SVG Filters

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters, css-filters

I have an image with a lot of different colors, and I want to create an output image that only has a set of distinct colors from the original image in it (let's say showing all pixels that are `#DEADFF`). Is there an easy way to do this? I have a couple of thoughts but don't think they work

1. Do some clipping with extreme `feColorMatrix` values

   - If I applied the matrix transformation of

   ```
   [ 1 0 0 0 -R ]   [ N 0 0 0 0 ]   [ 1 0 0 0 R ]
   [ 0 1 0 0 -G ]   [ 0 N 0 0 0 ]   [ 0 1 0 0 G ]
   [ 0 0 1 0 -B ] * [ 0 0 N 0 0 ] * [ 0 0 1 0 B ]
   [ 0 0 0 1  0 ]   [ 0 0 0 1 0 ]   [ 0 0 0 1 0 ]
   [ 0 0 0 0  1 ]   [ 0 0 0 0 1 ]   [ 0 0 0 0 1 ]
   ```

   - where `N` is a super big number and `R`, `G`, `B` are the target red/green/blue values we want, theoretically everything but our target R/G/Bs would get clipped, but this would break down if we had things that had `R`, `G'`, `B'`, where `G' != G` and `B' != B`
2. `feComposite` looked promising (specifically its `in` operator), but I didn't see any clean examples involving creating the image to filter against.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace one color using SVG filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639049/replace-one-color-using-svg-filters)

Comment: Haha the 256-int-long table values is a little inelegant but it might do the job – thank you!

Comment: Also that solution doesn't seem to be working on Chrome right now

Comment: It's still working on Chrome/Win10 for me.

Comment: I'm on OSX, v weird, but I was able to get it working in firefox